# Menu (Picture) does not fill width of my Joomla site

Tags: html, css, joomla

I have set up my picture menu and it is working correctly but I notice it does not fill the width of the website.

I have set all pictures to max-width: 100%; and height: auto; within the actual component but it doesn't want to fill the width of the website.

My Protostar template was set to Fluid already.

I'd like the picture menu to be responsive relative to the width of my website and when the screen size is reduce I'd like the same.

This is currently not the case.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is the link to my site:

```css
.image-title {
display: flex;
font-size: 30px;
color: white;
justify-content: center;
position: relative;
top: -70px;
line-height: normal;
}
.item-241 {
vertical-align: bottom;
padding: 0px;
display: table-cell;
}
.item-242 {
vertical-align: bottom;
padding: 0px;
display: table-cell;
}
.item-244 {
vertical-align: bottom;
padding: 0px;
display: table-cell;
}
.nav > li > a > img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

Comment: do you want so? - https://ibb.co/3kpRMNp

Comment: I actually only want the images to auto-resize and maximize on the browser.

Comment: this link does not work for me (((

Comment: I understood how. I'll do it now.

Comment: Please ask your Joomla questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  While there can be general purpose solutions which can be offered on SO, the audience at JSE has more intimate knowledge of the CMS, its features, as well as 3rd party extensions and they can advise you on best practices and common pitfalls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do everything right, you will get the desired result. Use the following css rules for the solution:

```
.nav:ntd-child(2) {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

In this rule, delete these lines that I pointed to.

```
.nav-tabs:before,
.nav-tabs:after,
.nav-pills:before, <--- delete
.nav-pills:after <--- delete {
    display: table;
    content: "";
    line-height: 0;
}
```

here I replaced `max-width` with `width`

```
.nav > li > a > img {
    width: 100%; 
    height: auto;
}

.item-241, .item-242, .item-244   {
    width: 33%; /*add this it*/
    vertical-align: bottom;
    padding: 0px;
    display: table-cell;
}

.nav-pills > li > a {
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 90%; /*add this it*/
}
```

I warn you that the native size of all pictures is different, which means that if you set one height for everyone (fixed), it will not be beautiful. In order to be beautiful, the pictures need to be hooked through the `background-image`, in the `div`.

Comment: did you succeed?

Comment: Thank you! I did all the changes you suggested but it is not displaying correctly on the two computers I tried: https://ibb.co/K9PWTdr
https://ibb.co/hLhVMrL

Comment: have you set the index for the child class? `.nav:ntd-child(2) {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}`

Comment: yes I added it under custom.css along with the .nav, .items and .nav-pills that you provided. Should I add those under template.css in the Protostar template of Joomla?

Comment: I have tested this on different screens too. Everything shows well. https://ibb.co/cwc4W15

Comment: yes add in template.css. And try adding `!important` - .nav:ntd-child(2) { display: flex!important;     justify-content: space-between; }

Comment: How are you doing with the layout?

Comment: It is working properly on 2 computers but another 2 computer it overlaps with the top menu beside COVID-19 https://ibb.co/K9PWTdr. Thank you for all the help. By the way, how can I fix the height of the images? Should all of the images have the same ratio?

Comment: for this section of the site, yes, it will be correct if all the pictures are of the same ratio. And the best thing will be if you upload images not through the `img` tag, into the `div`, using the `background-image` rule.

Comment: after playing around the code you gave me. Everything is working flawlessly now on 4 different computer and phone. I added back the .nav-pills:before, .nav-pills:after { that I have deleted and that solved the problem of it overlapping on the top menu. Format is perfect now. Thanks alot for the help! My website is beautiful now

Comment: Sometimes it's hard to give the right solution when you don't have the complete code at hand :) I was glad to help you!